# Android connection timeouts

Tags: java, android

In `HttpURLConnection` class there are two methods foe setting time outs.One is `setConnectTimeout(t1)` and other is `setReadTimeout(t2)`.What is the relationship between t1 and t2? Should `t1>t2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setConnectTimeout()` is a the timeout of the connection, meaning how long it takes to connect to the server

`setReadTimeout()` is a timeout for reading, meaning how long it takes to read from server, and if it takes longer than that it will timeout the read

In a way they don't have anything to do

Answer (score 4):

**setConnectTimeout(milliseconds)**:Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting. 
**setReadTimeout(milliseconds)**:Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up .